# Android BLE: knowing MTU on the GattServer side

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented BLE communications on Android. I'm negotiating the MTU on the client side using [requestMtu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestMtu(int)). This works well, as the client gets the MTU change on [onMtuChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onMtuChanged). However, I still don't have the means to know the MTU on the server side, only the client. I implement my own mechanism for fragmentation/segmentation as sometimes I'm sending reasonable amounts of data. I'd like to segment the data according to MTU size for faster communications. I'm currently sending 20 bytes at a time on the server side, which works but is slower. Is there a way to get the MTU on the server?

Answer (score 10):

The way I made this work was to wait for a connection, then create a connection with the device that connected via the `onConnectionStateChange(...)` function.

```
private final BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallback = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
      if (newState == Bluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED)
        device.connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, mGattCallback);
      super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);
}
```

This allowed me to requestMtu() on the resulting successful connection.

```java
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
      if (newState == Bluetooth.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        gatt.requestMtu(512);
      }
      super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

    }
  };
```

Comment: Super thanks man. One doubt though: Does the MTU change request has be to initiated from the server for this to work or do both the parties have to do the request MTU change from their respective sides: kind of a handshake, because that what I have done and works for me..?

Comment: But if BluetoothGattServerCallBack is in side of Server and BluetoothGattCallBack is in side of Client...how i call method device.connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, mGattCallBack); from BluetoothGattServerCallBack if mGattCallBack must be in side of client?

Answer (score 3):

The requestMtu call will lead to a Gatt MTU exchange between the client & server。The smaller mtu will be the final one in use。 
If you want to know the mtu size on the server side， just give a parameter big enough to the “requestMtu” call， and get the result in “onMtuChanged”。
Alternatively，see your btsnoop file on the platform & you will get exactly what the mtu size on the server is.

Comment: But the onMtuChanged method does not exist on the server side. How to you get the MTU?

Answer (score 3):

`BluetoothGattServerCallback` has the method `onMtuChanged` that you can override and directly obtain the MTU once negotiated (after request from central side):

```
@Override
public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
   super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
   this.mtu = mtu;
   Log.i(TAG, "New MTU: " + mtu + " , Status: " + status + " , Succeed: " + (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS));
}
```

Comment: My callback had different arguments:
onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status)
 {
   super.onMtuChanged(mBluetoothGatt,mtu, status);
   Log.i("BLEService", "New MTU is " + mtu);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Per the Bluetooth Core specification document, in 3.F 3.2.8:

> A device that is acting as a server and client at the same time shall use the
>   same value for Client Rx MTU and Server Rx MTU.

Therefore, use MTU you get through GATT client API, it has to be the same.

Comment: I'm not using the device as both server and client. Is there something else?

Comment: Android implements both Client and Server, so they are both here, even if you dont use them explicitly. Even if you dont use any other mechanism from the client API, this should give you the value you need.

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm only advertising the device on the network, not scanning. Your suggestion makes sense if the device is doing both, but I still don't understand how I can get the MTU on the server without scanning.

Comment: You're missing the fact the attribute protocol is symmetrical, there is always a server on a device, even if device is peripheral. Peripheral/Central distinction is just a matter of who initiates the connection at the lower level of the protocol.

Comment: Where did you read that? I'm capable of starting a device exclusively as a peripheral, both in Android and iOS. But anyway, the problem holds. If the device is not scanning (which peripherals shouldn't because it's battery intensive) I have no way of knowing the MTU on Android. What you are suggesting is that I scan anyway?

Comment: the server and client just stands on the ATT protocol, it have nothing to do with scanning or other topics. for the initial state of the connection, the MTU is the default value, i.e. 20 bytes and both side can actually change it after the friendly negotiation. I assume you are using the GATT server? you also can receive the callback of onMtuChanged(BluetoothDevice device, int mtu) if the MTU value changed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature now for BluetoothGattServerCallback is    onMtuChanged(BluetoothDevice device, int mtu)

For C# I used this signature:

```
        public override void OnMtuChanged(BluetoothDevice gatt, int mtu)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnMtuChanged: mtu is {0}", mtu);
        }
```